# Access point with `nmcli`

Tags: networking, debian, nmcli

I'm working on a Debian system:

```
# uname -a
Linux iot-gate-imx8 5.4.24-iot-gate-imx8-2.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 3 10:30:00 IDT 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a `MODEM` connection (which is active and working):

```
# nmcli con
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
MODEM               425b609c-c893-4178-b3c3-88a8f2124b33  gsm       ttyUSB2
Wired connection 1  679f5ed8-61f1-3cc4-bb4f-376b4e841276  ethernet  --
Wired connection 2  417df684-700b-337c-8737-9e9ee07af12c  ethernet  --
```

I want to set up an access point using `nmcli`.
I install `dnsmasq`:

```
# sudo apt install dnsmasq
```

then I set up my connection:

```
# nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 mode ap con-name test ssid test ipv4.method shared
```

The command seems to be successful:

```
# nmcli con
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
MODEM               425b609c-c893-4178-b3c3-88a8f2124b33  gsm       ttyUSB2
test                f4936a89-11cd-4057-b481-1f62b776194b  wifi      wlan0
Wired connection 1  679f5ed8-61f1-3cc4-bb4f-376b4e841276  ethernet  --
Wired connection 2  417df684-700b-337c-8737-9e9ee07af12c  ethernet  --
```

When I try to connect to the network `test`, I get some problems:

1. a Windows 10 machine manages to connect, but then it tells that there is no Internet (and I can't see any valid IP address assigned to the machine);
2. an Android machine cannot connect to `test`, it seems that it has a problem with the IP assignment.

=-=-= ADDED =-=-=

The command

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager | tail -30
```

returns:

```
Jan 11 12:08:51 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) <MAC_ADDR_1>
Jan 11 12:08:51 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.0.43 <MAC_ADDR_1>
Jan 11 12:08:51 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) <MAC_ADDR_1>
Jan 11 12:08:51 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.0.43 <MAC_ADDR_1>
Jan 11 12:08:51 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.0.43 <MAC_ADDR_1>
Jan 11 12:08:51 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.0.43 <MAC_ADDR_1> <DEVICE_1>
Jan 11 12:09:53 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) <MAC_ADDR_2>
Jan 11 12:09:53 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.0.229 <MAC_ADDR_2>
Jan 11 12:09:53 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) <MAC_ADDR_2>
Jan 11 12:09:53 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.0.229 <MAC_ADDR_2>
Jan 11 12:09:54 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.0.229 <MAC_ADDR_2>
Jan 11 12:09:54 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.0.229 <MAC_ADDR_2> <DEVICE_2>
Jan 11 12:11:44 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) <MAC_ADDR_3>
Jan 11 12:11:44 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.0.217 <MAC_ADDR_3>
Jan 11 12:11:44 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) <MAC_ADDR_3>
Jan 11 12:11:44 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.0.217 <MAC_ADDR_3>
Jan 11 12:11:44 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPDISCOVER(wlan0) <MAC_ADDR_3>
Jan 11 12:11:44 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPOFFER(wlan0) 192.168.0.217 <MAC_ADDR_3>
Jan 11 12:11:45 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPREQUEST(wlan0) 192.168.0.217 <MAC_ADDR_3>
Jan 11 12:11:45 <HOST> dnsmasq-dhcp[18301]: DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.0.217 <MAC_ADDR_3>
```

=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-

Could anyone provide some insight, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check these solutions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234552/create-wireless-access-point-and-share-internet-connection-with-nmcli

Comment: Yeah, I did. I found another solution: create the access point network via `hostapd`. This doesn't resolve the current issue, though, so I'm not posting it here (the procedure is quite unrelated).

Answer (score 0):

does the journalctl show anything interesting?

Comment: Please see the added part in the question! Thanks!